# MapRequestHandler - 404.0 Error when routing .html from .aspx in IIS 8.0

Tags: html, asp.net, iis

I am using URL Rewriting in `Asp.net` framework 4.0 and I am replacing aspx with an html extension (i.e. I am using routing like Login.aspx as Login.html). But it is showing error a 404 *(not found)* error. In short, URL Rewriting with .html extension is not working on IIS 8.0. Without .html (like Login.aspx with login), it is working fine.

Check this :

- [theprojectjugaad.com/Login.html](http://www.theprojectjugaad.com/Login.html) (404.0 error)

  [image]
- [theprojectjugaad.com/Register](http://www.theprojectjugaad.com/Register) (Working fine)

Please help me to solve this.

**Global.asax**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        RegisterRoutes();
}

private static void RegisterRoutes()
{
        System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add(
                "Login", new System.Web.Routing.Route("Login.html",
                                    new DisplayRouteHandler("~/Login.aspx")));
}
```

Comment: What does your URL rewriting rule look like?  Also, have you tried doing what the error message says - turning on fail request tracing?

Comment: @FarmerBob, I will update rule soon. I am using rule in Global file.

Comment: @FarmerBob, check updated post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the Application Pool from Classic to Integrated fixed the issue.